# save $index in ng repeat angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a small problem I would save $ index to reuse it in the next ng repeat,

I explain, I created an object array that has the same size as my json array

this is my object array

```
 $scope.valeur[index] = {
                    'BODY':"",
                    'TYPE':"",
                    'PARAMETRE': ""
                };
```

this is a picture of my json

[image]

So my $ index run 2 time and then 5 time and me I would like that from the first round it save the variable and it starts the next ng repeat has the previous value (here 1)

this is my ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, item) in dataApi track by $index" >
    <div u ng-repeat="(key, itemHead) in item track by $index" ng-init="firstIndex == undefined ? firstIndex = $index : firstIndex = $index+firstIndex" >
        {{firstIndex }}
    </div>
</div>
```

I tested with the ng-init but I have nothing concrete

i someone can help me

thanks in advance

EDIT

here is that i want, so it's with the ng-repeat of the 2nd level that I want to save the value,

1st round of ng-repeat level 2
Index starts at 0
And finished at 1

2nd round of ng-repeat level 2
Index starts at 2 (value of previous $index+1)
And finished at 6

heres is a picture

[image]

Because I need to have a consistency with my object array

example
1st round
Index = 0 $ scope.value [index]
Index = 1 $ scope.value [index]
 2nd round
Index = 0 $ scope.value [index]

So problem because my index is 0 and not 2

Or else I would just need a variable that counts the number of times I am switching to the ng repeat lvl2

Answer (score 2):

try using `$parent.$index` and you don't have to save it temporarily.

Comment: My div parent has just 2 information c is not the right way, I would like to save the 2nd level index

Comment: The question is why you need to save it? and even you have to save it, you are probably outting the ng-init in wrong place, at that point its entered in new child scope, so either use the ng-init in outer div or in any intermediate dom (if you have).

Comment: well, why you want add the last index with it? lets assume you are at 10th index and that sub array have only 3 items, so, would you going to start from 9th index? why don't you iterating simply all the nested array as a fresh iterating? exactly what you are trying for?

Answer (score 2):

here is a working example and if you dont want to use `ng-init` then `$parent.$index` is a good option:

```html
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="test">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        angular.module('test',[])
                .controller('Main',function($scope)
                {
                    $scope.options = [
                    [{opt:'1'},{opt:'2'},{opt:'3'}],
                    [{opt:'1'},{opt:'2'},{opt:'3'}]
                    ];
                });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Main">
{{'ng-repeat'}}
<div ng-repeat="data in options" ng-init="first = $index"><div ng-repeat="d in data">first:{{first}}.data:{{d.opt}}current:{{$index}}</div></div>
{{data}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Gazano you want to initialize next second ng-repeat from the first $index? right?